# Atom node-debugger gives two errors on startup

Tags: node.js, atom-editor

With Node 8, I install [Node Debugger](https://atom.io/packages/node-debugger) into Atom, and set the path to Node.  Then I try to run a simple script with F5.  I get the errors:

`Connection attempt 1 to node process on 127.0.0.1:5858 failed
(node:77739) [DEP0062] DeprecationWarning: node --debug and node --debug-brk are invalid. Please use node --inspect or node --inspect-brk`

How do I fix this?

Comment: It seems that there is already an [issue](https://github.com/kiddkai/atom-node-debugger/issues/234) open on the repo for this deprecation problem. The package needs to be updated, however it seems like there hasn't been much activity in the last few months.

Comment: @saadq Please convert your comment into an answer so I can give you the  points.  It didn't occur to me that this package wouldn't have been updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is already an [issue](https://github.com/kiddkai/atom-node-debugger/issues/234) open on the repo for this deprecation problem. The package needs to be updated, however it seems like there hasn't been much activity in the last few months.

Answer (score 0):

If you run your script via command line you can use the proper flag.

```
node ~/my-path/my-file.js --inspect=5858
```